# Loop 2 arrays and check if equal values and update data C#

Tags: c#, arrays

1. I have one array with max 2 ids of pictures but it also could be
   null or just 1 id on server side.
2. Second array is coming from client side and it also can have 2, 1 or
   0 elements.

Now I need to check if id from client side is in the array on server side and if yes delete old one and replace with new.

Example:

```
oldId(1 , 2)
newID(2 , 3)
if ([2] != [1] && [2] != [2]) {
  //ignore replacing oldId array
}
if ([3] != [1] && [3] != [2]) {
  //replace array 
}
```

so at the end I should have array(3 , 2)

Thank you.

Comment: Your first sentence contradicts the second one.

Comment: where and why exactly?

Comment: maybe I'm wrong, but it looks like need to be: 'check 2 != 1 && 2 != 2' (it's **true**) then you **need do something** (e.g. replace 2 with 2), correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According your example:

```
foreach(var item in clientArray)
{
    if(!serverArray.Contains(item))
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

but your sentence (above example) says something the opposite.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if the database data is the old Id and the client's data is the new Id but if that is the case then try this..

```
int[] oldId = { 1, 2 };
int[] newId = { 2, 3 };

for(int i = 0; i < newId.Length; i++)
{
    int index = Array.IndexOf(oldId, newId[i]);
    if(index == -1) // -1 if value does not exist
    {
        oldId[i] = newId[i];
    }
}
```